# the import * - slows the application?

Tags: flash, actionscript

when i write:

```
import flash.display.*; // importing all the classes of display

import flash.display.MovieClip; // importing only one class
```

and likewise other classes, so the question is: If i import all the classes from some package the application will work more slowly than if I import only the REALLY needed classes?

is that true or false?

Comment: And how much it will be slower?, 1 second, 2? or more?, let's say in a big application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be false. Importing more classes from the namespace should not affect the speed of your application as it does not cause any more code to be run.

Comment: I would think it would only affect compile/build time, but even that shouldn't be much for smaller projects. From my understanding it only adds classes to the final .swf that is used in the code, so importing all shouldn't add any additional classes.

Comment: +1 for short and correct, I think you should mention that it is still probably a bad idea since you have no vision of dependencies.

Comment: I don't think it _actually_ compiles in any Class unless there's a variable in your Class scope of that type.  However, code completion in both Flash and Flash Builder add the import lines for you, so why would you ever use import flash.display.* or whatever?